# Phaser P2 Player kick ball and add Impulse on hit

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need help for a school project and want to code a game like Headsoccer in Phaser with P2 Physics, I already have two players, two goals and a ball that can collide with each other. Now I want to add a kick animation and a hitbox for the kick which when kicking the ball applies an impulse or some sort of force from the kick. How could I do that?

Thanks.

Here is some Code 
Would be nice if you can give me some advice on how to structre my code better or if i can change something

```
function create() {
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 500);
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    //game.physics.p2.enable([ player, player2, fussball, goal, latte ], true);
    //game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 200;
    game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'Spielfeld');
    game.physics.p2.gravity.y = 600;


    goal = game.add.sprite(35, 428, 'goal');
    game.physics.p2.enable(goal,true);
    goal.body.static = true;
    goal.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
    goal.body.data.shapes[0].sensor = true;

    player = game.add.sprite(100, 500, 'player');
    game.physics.p2.enable(player,true);
    player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    player.body.fixedRotation = true;
    player.body.clearShapes();
    player.body.loadPolygon('playerPhysics','player');


    player2 = game.add.sprite(500, 500, 'player');
    game.physics.p2.enable(player2);
    player2.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    player2.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    player2.body.fixedRotation = true;

    var shape = new p2.Circle();
    ball = game.add.sprite( game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'ball');
    game.physics.p2.enable(ball);
    ball.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    ball.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    ball.body.data.gravityScale = 1;
    ball.body.clearShapes();
    ball.body.addCircle(shape);
```

My game looks like this, and I showed the hitbox of Player 1 and Goal.

[image: Game screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have any code to work with, I'm assuming you have something like the [official Impact Events example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/impact-events) code in place.

In that case, you could play an animation when one of the players collides with the ball. In the example above, that would be changing this method to play the animation (instead of changing the sprite's `alpha`):

```
function hitPanda(body1, body2) {
    body2.sprite.alpha -= 0.1; // Remove/replace this line.
    // Add the playing of the kick animation.
    body1.play('kick');
}
```

In this same area you could then apply a speed boost to the ball.

Comment: Wouldnt then a speed boost apply to the ball everytime i press kick ? And how do i apply a speed boost in P2 Physics ? Thanks

Comment: "everytime I press kick": I think I missed this in your question - you wanted the kick to happen when the user did something, and not just when the two objects collided? Can you update your question with some code so we can see what you're trying to do and have something to start with? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve